# click an icon (in left bar) ,another icon is apperaing

Tags: 18.04

Yesterday ,I downloaded and installed Quartus 13.0 .I couldn't ADD the app TO FAVORITES,but I did it(I also added a picture) ,but when I click on it ,quartus is opening (good) ,but also another icon is appearing down the icon of quartus.How to solve it?
~Ubuntu 18.04.5
~Quartus 13.0 sp1 web edition
See what I mean:
[image: Picture]

Comment: Where did you create the `.desktop` file? Could you add output of `sudo apt install wmctrl; wmctrl -lp; sudo ps -ax` while Quartus is running